# How to extend a class in TypeScript and change one parameter but without overriding each method?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a TypeScript class to extend another class and automatically override each method of the base class, but in a generic way so I don't have to explicitly override each method:

For example:

```
class A {
  foo(string a, string b) { console.log(a + " " + b) }
  ...
  bar(number a, string b) { console.log(b + " " + a) }
}

class B extends A {
  // all methods from A regardless count and without overriding each of them should add "TEST" to second b parameter
}
```

which should be equivalent to:

```
class B extends A
{
  foo(string a, string b) { console.log(a + " " + b + " TEST") }
  ...
  bar(number a, string b) { console.log(b + " TEST" + " " + a) }
}

const b = new B()
b.foo("arg1", "arg2");
execution => "arg1 arg2 TEST"
```

I have tried overriding all methods from A in B and adding my logic but this doesn't scale well if I have many methods and many classes.

Comment: I really don't see how this is possible, with or without TypeScript... Maybe you could do something quirky with decorators but that would still require a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: To give you a bit of context, I generated GRPC clients with protoc to be called from ReactNative and I want to inject the authorization header on each method calls.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] that doesn't demonstrate a problem you're not having.  For example, `string a` is not valid TS syntax. I suggest you test your code in a standalone IDE to be sure the only issue present is the one you want to talk about.

Comment: (see prev comment)  Once you do that, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKbq8m) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?